# how to get the qty of items invoiced

Tags: magento-1.8, invoice, sales, sales-order

I'm creating a partial invoice and I'm unable to get the `qty invoiced` to send it to the payment gateway.

The code I'd written in my model for `capture()` is:

```
        if ($order->hasInvoices()) {
            foreach ($order->getInvoiceCollection() as $invoice) {
                foreach ($invoice->getAllItems() as $item) {
                    Mage::log($item->getQtyInvoiced()); // getting qty = 0
                }
            }
        }
```

also, for the next time I do want to create the invoice then `$order->hasInvoices()` returning `false`.

Is the above code is right? Any note on debug the **invoice items** will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean when you say 'also, for the next time I do want to create the invoice then $order->hasInvoices() returning false'?

Comment: means, if I'd invoiced 2 out of 5 items in the order then 3 of them are left to be invoiced later. and later on, if I do invoice the rest of them or less then the number left then there is no log entry(no execution of `if()` block)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getQtyInvoiced()` method you are using does not exist. You need to use

```
$item->getQty();
```

Then you should be all set.

**P.S.** For a full list of functions applicable to this object, refer to `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Invoice/Item.php`

Comment: I know, but magento internally has magic functions getter and setter. and in table `sales_flat_order_item` there is a column `qty_invoiced`

Comment: From what I understand the "getter/setter" methods are applicable for custom models, not predefined ones. Let me know how it pans out using the getQty() method.

Comment: you were right. `getQty()` is working fine. but what about the next time I create the remaining invoice. `if ($order->hasInvoices()) {` block does not execute. why?

Comment: To call the value in qty_invoiced column use getQtyInvoiced()

Comment: Be careful, getQtyInvoiced() seems to represent the ALREADY INVOICED quantity in Magento 1.9.2 - it is not the amount that will be paid for with the current invoice ..

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
if ($order->hasInvoices()) {
            foreach ($order->getInvoiceCollection() as $invoice) {
                foreach ($invoice->getAllItems() as $item) {
                    Mage::log($item->getQty());
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: `getQty()` is working now. but for the next time `if ($order->hasInvoices()) {` block does not execute. why?

Comment: This is essentially the exact answer that I posted?