# how can i get Invoiced Qty in transactional email

Tags: magento-1.9

When I ordered 5 items, "Total Qty" in order confirmation mail is correct.
But if I invoiced only 3 items, "total Qty" in invoice mail says 5.

so i wanted to make "Total Ordered Qty" and "Total Invoiced Qty" separately
how can i get the invoiced qty in total.phtml ???

path : base / default / template / sales / order / totals.phtml

```
<tr>
        <td colspan="3" ><strong>Total Invoiced Qty</strong></td>
        <td class="last" style="width:300px;">
        <strong>
       <?  **i don't know what to put in here. please help me**   ?>

        </strong>
        </td>

</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **getQty()** method of **item** object as follows.

```
$item->getQty();
```

You need to use existing **item** object in that file or create new **item** object as per need.

Comment: $item->getQty(); is for Ordered Qty not "Invoiced Qty"

Comment: I think it returns invoiced qty as per https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/17107/how-to-get-the-qty-of-items-invoiced